# AngularJS, $location causes a flicker after the animation, when using Firefox

Tags: angularjs

When a user presses a button, he gets redirected. Here's the button:

```
$scope.goToArgumentation = function(argumentation_id,startingposition){
    startingposition = startingposition || 1;

     $location.path("/" + argumentation_id).search({"sp": startingposition});
};
```

On the new page, an animation occurs. After that animation, the content of the animation disappears and reappears shortly after. A short flicker about 0.5 - 1 second) This happens in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

However, the flicker does not appear, when the button looks like this:

```
$scope.goToArgumentation = function(argumentation_id,startingposition){
    startingposition = startingposition || 1;

     window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/argumentation#!/' + argumentation_id + '?sp=' + startingposition;
};
```

I tried to figure out, why this is happening. My initial guess was, that [$location.path](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) does more than just redirect. However, I didn't find any more information regarding the flicker. My second guess was, that the problem may be about the webkit. But since the flicker does not occur, when I use `window.location.href`, I think, there must be some error in my code.

Does anyone know, why this is happening? And how I could prevent it?

The div, that gets animated:

```
<div class="move" ng-class="{'static': pos == 1, 'move-to-right': pos == 2}">
</div>
```

The css for the animation:

```
.static{

}

.move-to-right{
    transform: translate(200%, 0%);
}

.move {
    transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Here is the route:

```
.when("/:id",{
            controller: "MovingBlockController",
            templateUrl: "argumentation/show.html"
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the css-classes seems to fix this problem:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

But I still don't understand, why there is no flicker, when using `window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/argumentation#!/' + argumentation_id + '?sp=' + startingposition;`